# What does the two insde the square brackets in $_SERVER["arv"] stands for?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey Everyone what does the number two inside the square brackets? The id is not an array.

```
         $id = @$_SERVER["arv"][2];
```

Comment: `The id is not an array` Good thing we're not applying `[2]` to `id` then...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Var_dump($_SERVER) and see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `2` is an index for an array that is stored within an array. So when the first array `arv` is selected, if that is an array, then the number `2` will select the 3rd index of that array (0,1,2)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer settles the question, could you please check it so? If not, no big deal but it helps your reputation as well.